# Deform a compact Kähler manifold to a non Kähler one

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Could you give me an example of a compact Kähler manifold which analytically deforms to a non Kähler one?

For example, there is no hope to find a complex structure on a Hopf manifold in order to make it Kähler because of topological obstructions (the second Betti number is zero).

For instance, I think that the Iwasawa manifold should not have topological obstructions.

Of course, the algebraic counterpart of my question has an affirmative answer: complex tori of dimension greater than one give examples of manifolds that can be analytically deformed from an algebraic one to a non algebraic one (but still Kähler).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently, in this paper (http://www.jstor.org/pss/1970426) Hironaka constructs such a thing. I've still not read the paper or worked through the construction, but I keep seeing this given as a reference whenever people say that large deformations of Kahler manifolds may not be Kahler.

Comment: Thanks little brother, I had just found it!
I haven't read the paper neither...
Apparently he proves more: he constructs a family $V_t$ of 3-dimensional abstract non-singular algebraic varieties such that $V_t$ is projective for $t\ne 0$ but $V_0$ carries a positive $1$-cycle, algebraically equivalent to zero.

Comment: In the same paper Hironaka says that the same question is open for a family of 2-dimensional manifold.

By a paper of our big brother Dan Popovici, such an example cannot be of algebraic nature, since he proved that in a holomorphic family where all fibers are projective except at most the central one, all fibers are in fact projective.

Comment: And you want more? Are you looking for a family of non-algebraic Kahler manifolds that deform into a non-Kahler manifold? That might be tricky... Voisin has examples of Kahler manifolds that have the wrong topology to be algebraic, perhaps that's a place to start looking?

Comment: I do not need more. I was just curious... Anyway Voisin's examples won't work for the surface case: she gives constructions starting from dimension 4 I guess...

Comment: The surface case is known: a compact surface is Kahler iff its first Betti number is even (see f.ex. Buchdahl or Lamari in the Annals de l'Institut Fourier). This is a topological condition, so any deformation of a Kahler surface over a connected base is Kahler. So if you want to find non-algebraic Kahler manifolds that deform into something non-Kahler you have to start looking in dimension $\geq 3$, where we have no idea of the necessary and sufficient conditions to be Kahler.

Comment: You are right. Long life to Hironaka then...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Just so this question has an answer. All manifolds are compact.)

In **dimension one** every deformation of Kähler manifolds is Kähler because every Riemann surface is Kähler.

In **dimension two** the same is true but for less trivial reasons. A two-dimensional complex manifold is Kähler if and only if its first Betti number is even, which is purely a topological condition. The result then follows from the fact that the fibres of a deformation are diffeomorphic.

In **dimension three**, the result is no longer true; that is, there is a deformation of Kähler manifolds such that the central fibre is not Kähler. As Gunnar Magnusson pointed out in the comments, Hironaka gave an example of such a deformation in his [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970426) *An Example of a Non-Kählerian Complex-Analytic Deformation of Kählerian Complex Structures*. In fact, the construction used gives rise to a whole host of interesting phenomena in dimension three including the existence of a Moishezon manifold which is not projective. See the associated page on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka%27s_example) for more details.